# I am getting a null pointer exception with setImageUrl, i think from ImageLoader

Tags: java, android, image, url, android-volley

I have been trying to use a url to set an image on android for over a week. It seems like it would be so simple but I feel like I keep chasing my tail. I finally found out about Volley and my hopes were high but I still can't get it to work.

When I comment out the line where I setImageUrl the app does not crash. If I do not comment it out the line will execute along with there rest of the function, it seems, but then it crashes.

Have I not created my ImageLoader correctly?

Is my BitmapLruCache class not created correctly?

Is there an easier way to complete this basic task?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private RequestQueue mrq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);        
        ImageLoader mil = new ImageLoader(this.mrq, new BitmapLruCache(this));
        NetworkImageView img = new NetworkImageView(this);
        img.setImageUrl("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dTr/bez/dTrbeznT9.png", mil);
        layout.addView(img);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_main, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();


        }
    }
```

This is two versions of BitmapLruCache that I have tried.

```
public class BitmapLruCache implements ImageCache {
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    private static BitmapLruCache mInstance;

    public BitmapLruCache(Context ctx) {
        final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
        // Use 1/16th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 16;
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
                return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
            }
        };
    }

    public static BitmapLruCache getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new BitmapLruCache(ctx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mMemoryCache.get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mMemoryCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }
}


//  public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {
//      public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
//         final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
//         final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
//
//        return cacheSize;
//      }
//
//      public BitmapLruCache() {
//         this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
//      }
//
//    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
//         super(sizeInKiloBytes);
//     }
//
//     @Override
//      protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
//         return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
//     }
//
//    @Override
//      public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
//         return get(url);
//     }
//
//    @Override
//     public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
//         put(url, bitmap);
//     }
//  }
//
```

Thank you for your help and taking the time to read this.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: mrq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)...

Comment: My code is no longer crashing but It is not displaying the image. I have tried a few images from different servers that I know are there.